# Injecting HTML component selector in HTML in angular2

Tags: html, angular

I'm developping an app in Angular 2.3

Let's say I have this:

```
let dynamicTooltip = `<p ngbTooltip="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Test</p>`
```

And I want to inject this in my HTML like ?

```
editor.html.insert(dynamicTooltip);
```

and I want my ngbTooltip directive component to be loaded properly. How Is it possible ? I know in angular 1.x I used to do $.compile

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to search it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2 But be careful `Compiler` is not available in AOT https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11780

Comment: Check also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468